# Decision making vs AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I am doing a research about the difference between the `decision making` and the `Artificial intelligence`
How do these two subjects differ from one another? I didn't understand right now, are there a difference between these tow fields ? or one of them contains the other ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question would be a better fit on ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: Human decision making is researched in psychology. Agent based models are used to explain why humans prefer one option over another. AI is trying to automate the process with the help of computers.

Answer (score -1):

One definition of AI is that it is about agents taking rational actions, where the definition of rational is context-dependent. In Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (3rd edition), the authors say:

> We define AI as the study of agents that receive percepts from the
>   environment and perform actions.

And later:

> A rational agent is one that acts so as to achieve the best outcome or, when there is uncertainty, the best expected outcome.

Taking actions requires making decisions, and thus AI is about making rational decisions.

Of course, this doesn't mean that AI has a monopoly on decision making, as it is studied in business, psychology, and many other fields. But, with respect to your "decision tree" tag, decision trees are an AI technology for making decisions. (Decision trees are also usually learned from data.)

Comment: Actions can be taken without a decision. This is the case if a random generator is allowed to control a robot. The decision doesn't follow a rule but the underlying principle is probability theory.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez A random agent doesn't use any percepts from the environment. If you take percepts from the environment and use them for decisions, then you *must* make decisions. Your definition is no longer AI according to the AIMA definition. (Semantically one could also argue that even taking a random action requires making the decision to make that action.)